# Scale image on android file to file

Tags: android, image, image-scaling

I'm trying to scale image down before sending them to the back-end in my android app.
Currently I'm doing this with `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` and `inJustDecodeBounds` option. but it skips sensor information and as a result I'm getting rotated image. I'm fixing it by setting transformation matrix. Here is my code:

```
        File image = new File(uri.getPath());

        int angle = 0;
        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(image.getPath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(TAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    angle = 90;
                    break;

                case ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    angle = 180;
                    break;
                case ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    angle = 270;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (DEBUG) e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(angle);

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), options);

        if (angle != 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);
        }

        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d("COMPRESS", "scaled bitmap size: " + bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight());
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, buffer);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return buffer.toByteArray();
```

But this approach leads to OOM exceptions as it do everything in the memory and 
each non 0 degree image is loaded to memory twice.

Much better approach could be a direct scaling with saving sensor and other metadata information directly to file. I tried [ffmpeg libarary](https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android-java) for this but it is hanging.

I tried to google some other library but for all my requests it gives me an answers how to scale image in `ImageView`, `Canvas` etc.

So is there any other way to scale image on android in efficient way ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/ as it is able to handle orientation, resizing, and out of memory in one nice fluent API.

```
Bitmap smaller = Picasso.with(context)
   .load(new File(uri.getPath()))
   .resize(800, 800) // this is max size
   .centerInside()
   .get();

... carry on with compress code
```

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/226

Comment: hm, nice idea, I'll give it a try... Thanks!